# How does the following Java "continue" code translate to Scala?

Tags: scala

```
for (String stock : allStocks) {

    Quote quote = getQuote(...);
    if (null == quoteLast) {
        continue;
    }

    Price price = quote.getPrice();
    if (null == price) {
        continue;
    }

}
```

I don't necessarily need a line by line translation, but I'm looking for the "Scala way" to handle this type of problem.

Comment: Do you have control over the signature of `getQuote` and `getPrice`? if so you could have them return `Option[Quote]` and `Option[Price]`.

Comment: The rest of your for "loop" is missing. It currently does nothing.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't need continue or breakable or anything like that in cases like this: Options and for comprehensions do the trick very nicely,

```
val stocksWithPrices =
  for {
    stock <- allStocks
    quote <- Option(getQuote(...))
    price <- Option(quote.getPrice())
  } yield (stock, quote, price);
```

Answer (score 10):

Generally you try to avoid those situations to begin with by filtering before you even start:

```
val goodStocks = allStocks.view.
  map(stock => (stock, stock.getQuote)).filter(_._2 != null).
  map { case (stock, quote) => (stock,quote, quote.getPrice) }.filter(_._3 != null)
```

(this example showing how you'd carry along partial results if you need them).  I've used a view so that results will be computed as-needed, instead of creating a bunch of new collections at each step.

Actually, you'd probably have the quotes and such return options--look around on StackOverflow for examples of how to use those instead of null return values.

But, anyway, if that sort of thing doesn't work so well (e.g. because you are generating too many intermediate results that you need to keep, or you are relying on updating mutable variables and you want to keep the evaluation pattern simple so you know what's happening when) and you can't conceive of the problem in a different, possibly more robust way, then you can

```
import scala.util.control.Breaks._
for (stock <- allStocks) {
  breakable {
    val quote = getQuote(...)
    if (quoteLast eq null) break;
    ...
  }
}
```

The `breakable` construct specifies where breaks should take you to.  If you put breakable outside a for loop, it works like a standard Java-style break.  If you put it inside, it acts like `continue`.

Of course, if you have a very small number of conditions, you don't need the continue at all; just use the else of the if-statement.

Comment: Would this mean that getQuote has to be called twice for all the valid matches?

Comment: @deltanovember - Do you see any repeats of `getQuote` in my example code?  The value is stored; that's why there's a map _first_ and then a filter.

Comment: Your filter is really much more complicated than necessary, and there's absolutely no need to use breakable in the for comprehension version.

Comment: @Miles Sabin - Granted for this particular example, but I was assuming that return values being null was not the only case one would use a continue.  So I wanted to show methods that would work regardless of whether it's x==null or length==0 or whatever.

Comment: Breakable uses exceptions to implement this kind of control flow, right?

Comment: @Ken Bloom - Yes, but the expensive part of exceptions is creating a stack trace, and breaks skip that part.  So they're quite fast.  Not the best thing to use inside your tightest loops, but you shouldn't (as of 2.9.0) be using for loops then either.

Answer (score 7):

Your control structure here can be mapped very idiomatically into the following `for` loop, and your code demonstrates the kind of filtering that Scala's `for` loop was designed for.

```
for {stock <- allStocks.view
     quote = getQuote(...)
     if quoteLast != null
     price = quote.getPrice
     if null != price
    }{
      // whatever comes after all of the null tests
    }
```

By the way, Scala will automatically desugar this into the code from Rex Kerr's solution

```
val goodStocks = allStocks.view.
  map(stock => (stock, stock.getQuote)).filter(_._2 != null).
  map { case (stock, quote) => (stock,quote, quote.getPrice) }.filter(_._3 != null)
```

This solution probably doesn't work in general for all different kinds of more complex flows that might use `continue`, but it does address a lot of common ones.

Comment: Option's companion object's apply method will do the null check for you: replace the explicit null check in your variant with Option(<thing which might be null>) and you'll end up with mine.

Comment: @Miles: that's certainly correct, but it doesn't show off the `if` filters that the questioner probably wants to know about, and you have to explain what the `Option` constructor does.

Comment: I'm not so sure ... it looks to me like he has a classic instance of a problem which has a nicer monadic solution than one involving conditionals. Yes, there were conditionals in the question, but the implications was that the questioner didn't think the usage was idiomatic ... and I agree ;-)

Answer (score 4):

If the focus is really on the `continue` and not on the `null` handling, just define an inner method (the `null` handling part is a different idiom in scala):

```
def handleStock(stock: String): Unit {
  val quote = getQuote(...)
  if (null == quoteLast) {
    return
  }

  val price = quote.getPrice();
  if (null == price) {
    return
  }
}

for (stock <- allStocks) {
  handleStock(stock)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to embed the skipped-over code in an `if` with reversed-sense to what you have.

See http://www.scala-lang.org/node/257